# Website Not Ranking On Google

Tags: seo

Website rank drop on google News/Discovery since Oct 2023.
Website URL is iwmbuzz.com
I think some issue with the HTML theme, i am requesting for review and confirm.
I can see ’ code in HTML pages but same amp page has ’... So please confirm on encoding issue or not?
Also amp pages showing in google web story template.

I am not able to understand and not getting response from Google Forum

Please help

Below is the step wise process

In android when i search for website in google app, after clicking article in widget i am getting error, but after refresh article gets open. attaching screenshot. But in IOS screen scroll getting stuck.

As per understanding amp article getting open in Web Story template. Url for articles showing https://www.google.com/amp/story/s/

Step 1

[image]

Step 2

[image]

Step 3

[image]

Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with WordPress. You might have more luck on [Webmasters SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.